# subdivision surface modifier wrinkles mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, subdivision-surface

I'm using quads for an object, but when I use the subdivision surface modifier or even select "shade smooth" it gives these weird stripes. I have no clue how to make my object smooth now. I've checked all my normals, I've tried converting to tris and back, no luck there either.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Will upload blend file for inspection.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It may not be apparent in some views, but if you check face orientation your normals are inverted on half the mesh in a striped pattern.

[image]

A recalculate outside with everything selected should fix this.

[image]

[image]